# OpenCL clEnqueueWriteBuffer pass pointer error

Tags: c++, opencl

Is it necessary that array pointer passed to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` should malloc in the same scope?
Here is my code:

```
class int_matrix{
public:
  int_matrix(size_t size_row, size_t size_col) :
        _size_row(size_row), _size_col(size_col) { 
        element = (int*)malloc(size_row * size_col * sizeof(int));
    }
  friend int_matrix cl_prod_l(int_matrix& lhs, int_matrix& rhs);
private:
  int* element;
};
int_matrix cl_prod_l(int_matrix& lhs, int_matrix& rhs) {
  ...
  int_matrix return_val(lhs._size_row, rhs._size_col, 0); // Initialize elements in retrun_val
  cl_mem lhs_buffer, rhs_buffer, return_buffer;
/* config buffer */
  lhs_buffer = clCreateBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, M*K * sizeof(int), NULL, &err);
  rhs_buffer = clCreateBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, N*K * sizeof(int), NULL, &err);
  return_buffer = clCreateBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._context,
        CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, M*N * sizeof(int), NULL, &err);
  cl_kernel Kernel= clCreateKernel(int_matrix::_clconfig._program, ker, &err);
/* enqueue buffer */
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._cmdque, lhs_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, M*K * sizeof(int), lhs.element, 0, NULL, NULL);
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._cmdque, rhs_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, N*K * sizeof(int), rhs.element, 0, NULL, NULL);
  clEnqueueWriteBuffer(int_matrix::_clconfig._cmdque, return_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, M*N * sizeof(int), return_val.element, 0, NULL, NULL);
   ...
}
```

In this example, I find `lhs.element`, `rhs.element` and `return_val.element` cannot be passed in kernel. But when I change to some array `malloc` in this this function(copy the same value), the kernel can return the right result. 
So is there some limitations on the array pointer passed to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`?

Answer (score 0):

Emmm...
I find the answer my seld, `cl_mem` object and `int* element` should be put in the same scope.